# Swift 3 - UserDefaults Cleared Automatically With No Reason

Tags: ios, swift3, userdefaults

I keep the user logged in using UserDefaults, but sometimes the user got logged out with no reason. When I debugged this case, I found that the UserDefault is null!

Note: I do not clear the values unless the user tap on logout button.

**Edit:**

Here is some code:

When the user logs in, I save the token using:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("Bearer \(actualJson["access_token"].stringValue)", forKey: "access_token")
UserDefaults.standard.set("\(actualJson["refresh_token"].stringValue)", forKey: "refresh_token")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Each time I get 401 error from server (token expire) I get new ones using the refresh_token:

```
AccountService.refreshToken(refreshToken: UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "refresh_token") != nil ? UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "refresh_token")! : "", callback: { (json) in

    // set user defaults
    UserDefaults.standard.set("Bearer \(json["access_token"].stringValue)", forKey: "access_token")
    UserDefaults.standard.set("\(json["refresh_token"].stringValue)", forKey: "refresh_token")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()  
})
```

In AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "access_token") != nil && UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "refresh_token") != "" {
            // go to home
}
```

In the previous code, `UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "refresh_token")` is null. Although I'm sure I did not clear the value

Comment: Can't help anything without seeing code.Just check whether did you added code for clearing userdefaults in appdelegate or someother files.

Comment: @DSDharma I updated the question

Comment: Maybe the result from server it not good when you refreshing the token, like `json["refresh_token"].stringValue` is nil.

Comment: What json do you get on your session expire case where you refresh the token. Have you validated that?

Comment: there is only two reasons of user default value getting empty, 1.) you are updating or Removing it somewhere 2.) you are updating two values with key at same time. try checking for null before setting the value

Comment: @AkashSinghSisodia I might be updating values for a key in same time. I'll check that. Thanks

Comment: Don't use `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()`. Not only it's been useless since iOS8 but it can even create issues (race condition, lag, etc).

Answer (score -1):

The NSUserDefaults string could also get overreleased by a dangling pointer. If an autoreleased object is being assigned to a place that's supposed to be retained, and the NSUserDefaults string is being allocated in its place, when the "owner" of the deallocated object tries to release it, it will release this string instead.